# Changing images from BGR to RGB

Tags: python, image, opencv

I used the code below to plot the pictures that were predicted wrong. When the pictures are displayed I see that the pictures seem to be in the format BGR.

I found methods to do this for a single picture but not for a list of pictures
Is there a way how I can change the colors to RGB within this block of code?

this is the code I used to plot the images:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
for i in range(10):
    err_index = errors[errors['error']==1].index[i]
    plt.subplot(2,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(X_test[err_index].reshape(224,224,3))
    plt.xlabel("ture is {}, predicted as {}".format(np.argmax(y_test[err_index]), y_pred[err_index]))
```

Edit--
Sorry pasted the wrong code.
I tried to add a line with cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB but that didn't work. Really new to all this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am pretty sure this has been asked, and answered, several times, but it's actually faster for me to put this here than to search: since you're using numpy, this:

```
img_rgb = img_bgr[:, :, ::-1]
```

Also, given you're getting a BGR format, you're probably using OpenCV, so also this:

```
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

See [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html).

Comment: "I am pretty sure this has been asked, and answered, several times, but it's  -actually faster for me to put this here than to search" -- sort of like "I know there's a garbage bin nearby, but it's easier to just dump my waste on this lawn, and if anyone else cares about it, they can clean it up." Thanks.

Comment: @Dan, hm... I mean, I am not the one that asked the question, was I?
The was I see it, keeping the metaphor, it's more like "I know there is a garbage truck coming tonight, but I will pick up this wrapping I see on the ground and put it in the trash can myself". Am I missing something here? Am I actually supposed to search and find an answer and mark as "duplicate" instead of answering, when answering is faster (and maybe more useful)?

Comment: Yes, you should look for duplicates and mark the question as such if appropriate, before answering. It doesn't matter what's faster -- otherwise we'd end up with a mountain of very similar trivial question/answer pairs, which would get harder and harder to navigate and manage. (Problem is that once it has an accepted and upvoted answer, it will stick around and won't be cleaned up.) The goal here isn't to answer every single question posted. | You're right that OP should have spent more effort before asking this question.